# How do I send a JSON data while deleting in JqGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

Jqgrid inline editing sends `JSON` data. But Inline delete sends `FORMs data` 
. I need to send data to web method using JSON data only

heres how I inserted delete button in grid

colmodelMob is my `colModel` array

```
  colmodelMob.push(
                {
                    label: "Edit Actions",
                    name: "actions",
                    width: 100,
                    formatter: "actions",
                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: true,
                        editOptions: {},
                        addOptions: {},
                        delOptions: {}
                    }       
                });
```

Its basically because a confirmation box pops up asking server conformation for row delete. But i dont need that I need my data to be sent as JSON else it wont hit the `webmethod`.

Comment: Please include in *all* your questions the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use, and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: @Oleg im using old jqgrid version 4.4.4 . Its the free version (Trirand jqGrid )

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid uses [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to communicate with the server. To send the data in JSON format one have to do two things:

1. One should encode the data in JSON format. One uses typically `JSON.stringify` for encoding.
2. One should use the option `contentType` option set to `"application/json"` or `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` value. It includes HTTP header `ContentType` in the request. The header informs the server, that the data, sent to the server, are encoded in JSON format.

Optionally one can use `dataType: "json"` option too. One uses the option if the response on the Ajax call should contain JSON encoded data too.

Now about the implementation of the above requirements inside of jqGrid. jqGrid can use jQuery.ajax in many places. You use retro version 4.4.4 of jqGrid. It has much less possibilities, and it was developed at the time of very old web browsers, old jQuery and so on. I remind you that at the date of publishing of jqGrid 4.4.4 one used Chrome 24, Firefox 18, Internet Explorer 10, Safary 6.0.2. IE8 (and Internet Explorer at all) was the mostly popular web browser on Desktop (under Windows only). One works now with Chrome 54, Firefox 50, Microsoft Edge 38 and Internet Explorer 11, Safari 10. Do you really believe that jqGrid 4.4.4 will good work with the modern web browsers? I'd strictly recommend you to update to the current version (4.13.5) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

If you still have to use jqGrid 4.4.4 then you should use

```
{
    label: "Edit Actions",
    name: "actions",
    width: 100,
    formatter: "actions",
    formatoptions: {
        keys: true,
        delOptions: {
            serializeDelData: function (postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            ajaxDelOptions: {
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One have to set the options of `delGridRow` in many different plases depent on the usage other methods. The problem is: one uses the `delGridRow` method not only directly, but indirectly. For example `formatter: "actions"`, `navGrid`, `inlineNav` uses inline editing or form editing options. You have to use the corresponding deep placed options to specify your custom options of `delGridRow`. Free jqGrid has *jqGrid options*, which allows to specify common options for all indirect calls of the methods. One can use `inlineEditing`, `formEditing`, `formDeleting`, `formViewing`, `searching` to specify the *default* options used of all the methods. Thus you could use jqGrid options

```
inlineEditing: {
    keys: true
},
formDeleting: {
    serializeDelData: function (postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    ajaxDelOptions: {
        contentType: "application/json"
    }
}
```

After that you can just remove `formatoptions` property of `formatter: "actions"`. If you use `navGrid`, then it will use the same options during deleting too.

You can read more about the new way of specifying the options in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods).

By the way, you could have close problems with inline editing. You should probably use `ajaxRowOptions` option and `serializeRowData` callback of jqGrid  to make JSON encodding during inline editing. Free jqGrid supports the same options and allows you to use `ajaxSaveOptions` and `serializeSaveData` inside of `inlineEditing` additionally.